# jQuery mousemove direction, get correct distance

Tags: jquery, mousemove, direction, jquery-hover, jquery-calculation

Howdey, i need to create a direction aware hovering effect, but stuck at the correct calculation. (Is it a calculation problem or rather a wrong markup?)

Here's [what I've done](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/t4EME/2) so far:

The left and right arrows works as expected, but up and down fails. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

```
$("#circle").on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var elem = $(this),
        arrowT = $('.arrow.top'),
        arrowR = $('.arrow.right'),
        arrowB = $('.arrow.bottom'),
        arrowL = $('.arrow.left'),

        offset = elem.offset(),
        pageX = e.pageX - offset.left,
        pageY = e.pageY - offset.top,
        side = {
            top: pageY < (elem.height() / 2),
            left: pageX < (elem.width() / 2),
            bottom: pageY > (elem.height() / 2),
            right: pageX > (elem.width() / 2)
        };


    arrowT.css({
        top: side.top ? pageY - arrowT.outerHeight() : null
    });
    arrowR.css({
        right: side.right ? -(pageX - (elem.width() - arrowR.outerWidth())) : null
    });
    arrowB.css({
        bottom: side.bottom ? -(pageY - (elem.height() - arrowB.outerHeight())) : null
    });
    arrowL.css({
        left: side.left ? pageX - arrowL.outerWidth() : null
    });
});
```

Comment: The left and right arrows works as expected, but up and down fails...

Comment: I also notice that if you move your mouse too fast, everything just fails altogether, though I don't know if there's any solution to that or not.

Comment: Okay, i think the problem with fast "mousemoving" can be remedied by using settimeout, or similar...

Comment: "Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?" No because you haven't explained what it's supposed to do

Comment: "The left and right arrows works as expected, but up and down fails... "

Comment: @popnoodles I think that's obvious, right? However, I'll explain a bit for you: If the user moves the mouse out of the box, the arrows slides out (in observance of the mouse position...) Like the left and right arrows do ;)

Comment: Perhaps the problem lies also on the markup?

Comment: You can try setting some limits for the outerbounds of the top and bottom region? http://jsfiddle.net/t4EME/3/

Comment: @eleven11 Nice... Another problem comes up, any ideas how to let the left and right links work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/t4EME/7/

Here is a working version with links

```
        top: pageY < (elem.height() / 2) && pageY  > 0 ,
        left: pageX < (elem.width() / 2) && pageX  > 0,
        bottom: pageY > (elem.height() / 2)  && pageY  < elem.height(),
        right: pageX > (elem.width() / 2) && pageX  < elem.width()
```

Changed to absolute positioning as the margin was hiding the links

Comment: Yeah, nice... You're great! :-*

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with the body height changing as the elements are moved. Stick a wrapper on it whose size doesn't change and they work

http://jsfiddle.net/t4EME/4/

```
#wrap
{
    height:1000px; overflow:hidden;
    padding-top:100px;
}


<div id="wrap">
    <div id="circle">
        <a href="#" class="arrow top"></a>
        <a href="#" class="arrow right"></a>
        <a href="#" class="arrow bottom"></a>
        <a href="#" class="arrow left"></a>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: `<a href="#" class="arrow top"></a>` etc.

Comment: In the code given none of those link to anywhere and nothing is bound to them. Impossible to even guess again.

Comment: not now ;) by the way... if you hold your mousedown and move, then the `#wrap` will move too

Comment: And you think really to open another question for this problem is better, than to leave this question a bit open?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps. That was because the element size changes on moving mouse over it.

http://jsfiddle.net/t4EME/5/

```
topc = $('#circle').position().top;
widk = $('#circle').height();
$("#circle").mousemove( function(e) {
    var elem = $(this),
        arrowT = $('.arrow.top'),
        arrowR = $('.arrow.right'),
        arrowB = $('.arrow.bottom'),
        arrowL = $('.arrow.left'),

        offset = elem.offset(),
        pageX = e.pageX - offset.left,
        pageY = e.pageY - offset.top,
        side = {
            top: pageY < (elem.height() / 2),
            left: pageX < (elem.width() / 2),
            bottom: pageY > (elem.height() / 2),
            right: pageX > (elem.width() / 2)
        };   
if(e.pageY>topc && e.pageY<topc+widk) {
$('.top').css({
    top: side.top ? pageY - arrowT.outerHeight()  : null
});
$('.right').css({
    right: side.right ? -(pageX - (elem.outerWidth() - arrowR.outerWidth())) : null
});
$('.bottom').css({
    bottom: side.bottom ? -(pageY - (elem.outerHeight() - arrowB.outerHeight())) : null
});
$('.left').css({
    left: side.left ? pageX - arrowL.outerWidth() : null
});
}
});​
```

Comment: I know the question is already answered, but still I posted this one. I solved it much earlier but didn't know how to post code on stackoverflow. :P

Comment: Hee, no prob ;) Your solution looks much clearer, thanks a lot!